# securing access to an app engine service

Tags: php, security, google-app-engine, authentication

I have a GAE java service with the following access points:

getCost(id)

setCost(id,newCost)

on domain: myService.appspot.com

I also have a front end php app on: frontend.different-domain.com

that will need to be able to access those two end points. getCost can be publicly accessible by anyone but  I was wondering how I could secure the setCost() endpoint to limit it to only requests coming from frontend.different-domain.com

I'd like to avoid random people calling setCost and changing the price of things.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible solution in your case would be to generate signature on php front end and include it in request data along with other parameters. Your AppEngine service then calculates signature on its own and if the calculated signature matches the signature you sent in request, the request is considered authentic.

You generate signature using some secret key, which is known only to your php frontend and App Engine backend. I am Python programmer, so I can't tell you how it will look in Java or php, but you need to perform the following steps:

In php app:

1. Concatenate your secret with request data, e.g. `SECRET_KEYid5newCost537`
2. Calculate signature as MD5 hash of the string above.
3. Include this signature in request.

In App Engine app:

1. Extract `signature`, `id` and `newCost` from request data.
2. Calculate `signature1` using the same algorithm as in php app (i.e. MD5 hash of secret key plus data extracted from request).
3. Compare `signature` and `signature1`. If they are equal the request is authentic.
4. Create your own logic based on the result of comparison.

This technique is somewhat close to how signing of requests works in oAuth. Refer to [oAuth documentation](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#signing_process) for more information.

Also if your use case is more complicated than stated in your question you may consider using [oAuth with your Java application](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/).

Answer (score 0):

An even simpler method will be using the X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid header: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/#Java_Asserting_identity_to_other_App_Engine_apps